# Trouble with assertions when testing PDF files

Tags: cypress

**Objective:**
To find distinctive data that has been encoded in a pdf and write assertions using cypress to ensure data accuracy.

**Observed Behavior:**
Assertions that have been written do not execute.
I have tried the assertions and Cypress skipped them.

**Cypress Automation Setup:**

***`\plugins\index.js`***

```javascript
const parsePdf = async (pdfName) => {
    const pdfPathname = path.join(repoRoot, pdfName)
    let dataBuffer = fs.readFileSync(pdfPathname)
    return pdf(dataBuffer);
};

module.exports = (on, config) => {
    on('task', {
        getPdfContent (pdfName) {
            return String(parsePdf(pdfName))
        }
    });
};
```

***Test File `admin.reports.spec.js`
(Uses pageObject classes)***

```javascript
import LoginPageObjects from "../../support/pageObjects/common.pageObjects/login.pageObjects";
import ReportsDelegateReportPageObjects
    from "../../support/pageObjects/common.pageObjects/reports.delegateReport.pageObjects";

import(LoginPageObjects);
import(ReportsDelegateReportPageObjects);

const loginPage = new LoginPageObjects();
const reportsPage = new ReportsDelegateReportPageObjects();

describe('Delegate Report Functionality', function (){

    beforeEach(() => {
        // Provides admin credentials
        loginPage.getAdminLogin();
        // Navigates to Report Menu, Selects Report, Downloads PDF report.
        reportsPage.getMenuReport();
    });

    it('should return the report and verify the data in it', function () {
        cy.readFile('C:/Users/michael.frazier/Downloads/delegate_report.pdf', 'base64').should('contain.value', "Report");
    });
});
```

**Steps I have Tried:**

I have used the `.should`, `.expect` commands, does not search the file.
Used `pdfparse` to read the file. Lots of Google Searches

Also, I did this as well and it was ignored.

```
it('tests a pdf', () => {
    cy.task('getPdfContent', 'delegate_report.pdf').then(content => {
            .should('contain', "Reports" });
       })
```

**The Ask:** Is there a way where I can download the file, read the file then parse the data inside it so a assertion can be made?
Can it be converted to something more easier to parse? (json, txt, etc?)

Any insight on this would be great.

Comment: are you getting any error ?

Comment: Cypress docs don't talk about using cy.readFile to read PDFs. Where have you seen it is useful?

Additionally and alternatively, why not to use PDF.js instead of Cypress or simply cover the functionality in the backend service unit tests, since the PDF generation has nothing to do with the consumer (a web application)?

Comment: @JoãoFarias i am wondering why there is no error or exception thrown

Comment: @PDHide - No, I am not getting any errors. It's just skipping the assertion.

Comment: What makes you think it's skipping the assertion?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - The cli does not execute the assertion. It just reads the file. Normally, you would see the assert in green executing.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to explain what you're seeing.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I edited the post as instructed.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I am more than open to understand a new way. I also have been working with this:

it('tests a pdf', () => {
  cy.task('getPdfContent', 'mypdf.pdf').then(content => {
    // test you pdf content here, with expect(this and that)...
  })
})

Comment: why are you not using the getPdfContent task set up in the first snippet for plugins/index.js?

Comment: @knr - I did, I just did not add it in the question. I will add it now.

Comment: @knr - added now

Comment: Your last example has several syntax errors--calling `.should` without chaining it to a subject, mismatched curly brackets, etc., but I'm guessing that your actual code didn't have those issues or Cypress would probably have just given you an error when it tried to load the tests. I _think_ with the code you show in that example you would want `cy.wrap(content).should('contain', "Reports")`.

Comment: Did you try something like this? `cy.readFile("./downloads/sample.pdf").should('contain', 'This is a small demonstration')`